# ListLinePlot with slope-dependent color

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I would like the line coloring in `ListLinePlot` to be `Red` if the slope is negative; i.e., `yn<yn-1` and `Blue` if the slope is positive.

A similar topic was solved for the `Plot` function using the normal vector but here I would not like to use interpolation.

Comment: If use interpolation, `InterpolationOrder->1` + `ColorFunction -> Function[{x,y}, Which[f'[x] < 0, Blue, f'[x] == 0, Red, True, Green]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False` could help. (Put here just for reference.)

Comment: Thank. This is a way to use Interpolation without really to use it !

Answer (score 6):

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomFunction[RandomWalkProcess[0.5], {0, 20}] // Normal // 
  First;
data2 = Partition[data, 2, 1];
cols = If[Last@Last@# < Last@First@#, Red, Blue] & /@ data2;

ListLinePlot[data2, PlotStyle -> cols]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Since I edited the question to include the word slope, here is a variant that uses three colors like the answer posted by @cvgmt.

```
SeedRandom[123];
data = Transpose[{Range[20], 
   Accumulate[RandomChoice[{-1, 0, 1}, 20]]}];
data2 = Partition[data, 2, 1];
cols = If[Last@Last@# == Last@First@#, Darker@Green, 
    If[Last@Last@# < Last@First@#, Red, Blue]] & /@ data2;
ListLinePlot[data2, PlotStyle -> cols]
```

[image]

---

*Explanation of the `Last@Last@...`*

After partitioning `data` in 2-tuples with an overlap of `1`, each entry has two items. `First@#` would refer to the first point and `Last@#` would refer to the last (second in this case) point. The `Last@First@#` would refer to the y-coordinate in the first point entry or the part `[[1,2]]` and `Last@Last@#` would refer to the part `[[2,2]]` or the y-coordinate of the second entry.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was meaning. I still need to be confident with istruction like Last@Last@# < Last@First@#. Great!

Answer (score 4):

- Here we also deal with the case when `y[n]==y[n-1]`.
- We use the `Sign` to get the sign of the slope and mapping to the colors by `{1 -> Green, 0 -> Gray, -1 -> Red}`.

```
Clear[data, line];
data = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}, {6,
    5}, {7, 5}, {8, 7}, {9, 6}, {10, 5}, {11, 8}, {12, 8}, {13, 
   8}, {14, 4}, {15, 4}, {16, 3}, {17, 2}, {18, 1}, {19, 5}, {20, 
   5}, {21, 5}, {22, 7}, {23, 8}};
line[{a_, 
   b_}] := {Sign[(b[[2]] - a[[2]])/(b[[1]] - a[[1]])] /. {1 -> Blue, 
    0 -> Green, -1 -> Red}, Line[{a, b}]}
BlockMap[line, data, 2, 1] // Graphics
```

[image]

- Histogram

```
Clear[data, polys];
data = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}, {6, 5}, {7, 5}, {8, 
    7}, {9, 6}, {10, 5}, {11, 8}, {12, 8}, {13, 8}, {14, 4}, {15, 
    4}, {16, 3}, {17, 2}, {18, 1}, {19, 5}, {20, 5}, {21, 5}, {22, 
    7}, {23, 8}};
polys = Partition[data, 2, 
    1] /. {p_, q_} :> {EdgeForm[Directive[White, JoinForm["Round"]]], 
     Sign[q[[2]] - p[[2]]] /. {1 -> Blue, 0 -> Green, -1 -> Red}, 
     Polygon[{p, q, Projection[q, {1, 0}], Projection[p, {1, 0}]}]};
Graphics[polys, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]